# Can I buy Samyang 14mm filter holder in North America?

Tags: filters, samyang

In January [Samyang announced a dedicated Samyang 14mm filter](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2014/01/24/samyang-announces-14mm-f2-8-lens-filter-holder) holder but for some strange reason it is only available in Europe.  Does anyone know if it can be purchased in Canada or the US?  Does a 10-stop ND filter exist for this system? (161mm x 139mm)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that only the European distributor has the SFH-14.  You could probably order it from eBay or get it imported, though it would be grey market and not have any warranty.  I could not determine if Samyang has any future plans to release it globally or not.